# Save List into a text file using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, text-files, addressbook

I am developing an Address Book using C#.

i have a list which is displayed in an DataGridView but I want to save the list and not the datagridview into a text file.

When the form loads i have the code:

```
string[] parts = line.Split(','); // the word line throws an error saying that it does not exist in the current context
Person p = new Person(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6]);
AddressBook.Persons.Add(p);
```

I then have this code in the datalayer to save the list:

```
string filePath = @"c:\test.txt";
p.ToString(); // it does not recognise p
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Search for keyword `Serialization`. XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, JavaScriptSerializer etc.

Comment: Errors speak of themselves. But we're going to need more code to see where you have a problem.

Comment: "It does not recognise p" -- Do you have a p variable in that scope? We need methods to see what it is you are specifically trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have this in my Person class and was hoping it would pick it up but im not 100% sure how.      public Person(string p, string p_2, string p_3, string p_4, string p_5, string p_6, string p_7)
        {
            this.p = FirstName;
            this.p_2 = LastName;
            this.p_3 = Address;
            this.p_4 = Town;
            this.p_5 = County;
            this.p_6 = PostCode;
            this.p_7 = PhoneNumber;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and easy to use method for writing into a file is File.WriteAllText( filePath, 
p.ToString()). You have also to override the method ToString in the class Person, so you can return the information you want to save to file, otherwise it will, as default, return the class' name as string.
If you need a speedest way you should use a StreamWriter.

Comment: Thanks for that. But why is list in string[] parts = line.split(','); not being recognised? When I try it in a foreach loop the text line is recognised but an error appears at foreach

Comment: How would I use the StreamWriter to save the text from the collection?

Comment: try line.Split(new char[]{','});

Comment: Here is an example of how to use the StreamWriter class: http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter